# Can we access custom object in as community user?

Tags: community, customer-community, partner-communities

I am trying to work with salesforce communities. The question is can I able to access custom object while I login as community partner user or  community costumer user.I have enabled communities. Assigned profiles to the community. Assigned tabs and objects in community. But I am not able to see custom objects. Kindly let me know how to work with this issue.

Comment: You are trying to access by code or want to see tab on community page.

Comment: No Code i have written in it. I want to see tab on community Page.

Comment: Hi, i know this is pretty old, but were you able to find a solution for this, I am playing around with a community but nothing is showing up, however when log in as admin it does show up my tabs

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to create tabs of that object which you want to give Access on community.
2. Give the accessbility of tabs and object on profile level.
3. Go Your Name-->Setup-->Customize -->Community-->Manage Community.
   Then click on **Edit** link. Then a pop up will appear and then click on "Tabs nad Pages" tabs and add your tabs into seleted part.

Comment: I have already worked as you said still i dint get the custom object tab in community.

Comment: Tab was not coming, So on profile have given the rights of tabs to user. On profile there is tab section (i think you know) where we can hide/off/on the tabs, have a look there.I think we are missing there.

Comment: It was also made to be visible on.I can see Tab if admin logs into community but i cant see tab if user logs into community.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your created custom object is in "Published" state or not.
I face the same issue and after so much finding i found that my custom object was on in development state so it was only visible to me and not the parter users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have are logged in with system administrator Profile.

In Lightning Experience, click on "Setup", Type "All Sites", Click on "Builder" hyperlink.

You will be directed to "Partner Portal" , On left hand side click on "Page structure", then select "edit Default Navigation". add the newly created object to the Menu Item.

If you have a dedicated user for partner portal , then make sure that the profile of the partner portal user has create and edit permission to the newly created object.